# Nested tables with related parent content

Tags: html-table, semantic-markup

Having a semantics issue. I have a basic table with a standard header and footer. Each row contains an order, beneath each row I need to display another table, that will contain a break down of costs relating to that order. Additionally, these inner tables will be displayed with a jQuery accordion to hide and show when required (but I'm just concentrating on the HTML for now)

[image: table containing the row "Order 1" followed by a row "Order 1 related table"]

How can I semantically approach this in HTML?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Package number</th>
        <th>Date placed</th>
        <th>Placed by</th>
        <th>Total cost</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Weds</td>
        <td>Jonno</td>
        <td>£15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Part number</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Qty shipped</th>
                    <th>Weight</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <td>18293</td>
                    <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>72</td>
                    <td>20Kg</td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Thurs</td>
        <td>Jonno</td>
        <td>£1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Jonno</td>
        <td>£7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuW7f/ - The problem here is that the row containing the inner table, is totally unrelated to the order row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a parent element you can use to group related rows, you can use `<tbody>` elements. A table can have multiple `<tbody>` elements:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Package number</th>
            <th>Date placed</th>
            <th>Placed by</th>
            <th>Total cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Weds</td>
            <td>Jonno</td>
            <td>£15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Part number</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Qty shipped</th>
                            <th>Weight</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>18293</td>
                            <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                            <td>72</td>
                            <td>20Kg</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Thurs</td>
        <td>Jonno</td>
        <td>£1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Jonno</td>
        <td>£7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Whether or not that makes your code more semantically correct is debatable.  You could also give your rows classes to indicate whether the row is a summary row or a detail row, or attributes to indicate relationships to other rows.  Semantically, it seems fine as it is to me.

By the way, you are missing some `<tr>` elements.  A `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, or `<tfoot>` element does not replace a `<tr>` element.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I didn't know you could do that.